# Way to validate date from cmd

Tags: java, validation, localdate

I need to validate somehow two dates, but I do not know which way is the best.
In mainclass I created objects which I are passed by constructor to `NBPParserEngine`.

```
package pl.parser.nbp;

import pl.parser.nbp.calculations.RateCalculations;
import pl.parser.nbp.validation.ConditionChecker;
import pl.parser.nbp.validation.ConditionCheckerService;
import pl.parser.nbp.historysystem.HistorySystem;
import pl.parser.nbp.historysystem.HistorySystemService;
import pl.parser.nbp.view.NbpParserView;

import java.time.LocalDate;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        NbpParserView nbpParserView = new NbpParserView();
        DataFetcher dataFetcher = new DataFetcher();
        HistorySystem historySystem = new HistorySystemService();
        RateCalculations rateCalculations = new RateCalculations();
        ConditionChecker conditionChecker = new ConditionCheckerService();
        NBPParserEngine nbpParserEngine = new NBPParserEngine(conditionChecker, dataFetcher, rateCalculations,
                historySystem, nbpParserView);


        String currency = args[0];
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse(args[1]);
        LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse(args[2]);

        nbpParserEngine.executeNbpParserEngine(startDate, endDate, currency);
    }
}
```

I need to validate if these two dates are good, because if not then `DateTimeParseException` is thrown. 
Should I validate it in main with `while` loop and scanner or which way?

Answer (score 1):

Use a try-catch statement, for example:

```
    LocalDate startDate = null;
    try {
        startDate = LocalDate.parse(args[1]);
    } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
        System.err.println("Start date \"" + args[1] + "\" is not a valid date.");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Do similarly for end date.

Search `java exception handling` or similar to learn more.

And yes, if your program is interactive, an alternative to reading the dates from the command line is reading from standard input using a scanner and looping until a valid date is entered. Again I think that a search will lead you to the building blocks you need for putting it together.